# Collating users and their scores

Tags: java

Is anything what could I improve on my code?

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class Helper {

    public static Map<User, BigDecimal> createPlayersScoreMap(List<User> users, List<Score> scores) {
        List<User> players = getPlayers(users);
        Map<User, BigDecimal> playersScoreMap = new HashMap<User, BigDecimal>();

        for (User player: players) {
            BigDecimal sumScore = new BigDecimal(0);
            for (Score score: scores) {
                if (player.equals(score.getPlayer())) {
                    sumScore = sumScore.add(score.getResult());
                }
            }
            playersScoreMap.put(player, sumScore);
        }
        return playersScoreMap;
    }

    private static List<User> getPlayers(List<User> users) {
        List<User> filteredUsers = new ArrayList<User>(users);
        for (Iterator<User> it = filteredUsers.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            if (!it.next().isPlayer())
                it.remove(); 
        }
        return filteredUsers;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

`Helper` is not a good class name. You should be able to come up with something that provides more context to what the functions are doing.

In `getPlayers()`, I would loop and add instead of adding all and then removing.

```
private static List<User> getPlayers(List<User> users) {
    List<User> filteredUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
    for (User user : users) {
        if (user.isPlayer()) {
            filteredUsers.add(user);
        }
    }
    return filteredUsers;
}
```

I also added curly braces around the if block. It's not necessary, but it will prevent errors if you need to add an extra line later. You also included them in `createPlayersScoreMap()`, so it's best to be consistent.

If you have a large number of players and scores, you can make `createPlayersScoreMap()` more efficient (in terms of Big O processing). If `n` is the number of users and `m` is the number of scores, the method is currently O(n*m). However, if you sum all the scores first and then filter the players, you can get O(n+m).

```
public static Map<User, BigDecimal> createPlayerScores(List<User> users, List<Score> scores) {
    List<User> players = getPlayers(users);
    Map<User, BigDecimal> playerScores = new HashMap<User, BigDecimal>();

    for (Score score: scores) {
        User player = score.getPlayer();
        BigDecimal sumScore = score.getResult();
        if (playerScores.containsKey(player) {
            sumScore = sumScore.add(playerScores.get(player));
        }
        playerScores.put(player, sumScore);
    }
    Map<User, BigDecimal> filteredScores = new HashMap<User, BigDecimal>();
    for (User player : players) {
        filteredScores.put(player, playerScores.get(player));
    }
    return filteredScores;
}
```

I also change the name of the function/variable. They type system makes it obvious that you are dealing with a `Map`, you don't need to include it in the variable name. If the calling method has `List`s and `Map`s that deal with players and scores, then it might be acceptable to include the type as part of the variable name.

Comment: In the original code there is a `new BigDecimal(0)` this should be replaced with `BigDecimal.ZERO`, otherwise this review covers it all I think.

Comment: @bowmore: Good catch. I've never actually used `BigDecimal`, so I didn't know that existed.

Comment: I think you can also eliminate the filteredScores Map. After all in playerScores, only those users are missing that are players without a score. So the second loop can simply loop users and add en entry for users that are players without a score.

Answer (score 0):

The `Helper` is an absolutely ridicoulus class name. How about `PlayerScoreMap`? This might be a good idea because `createPlayerScoreMap` is actually a constructor! (As evidenced by the name).

The whole `getPlayers` helper is unneccessary, and backwards: All this does is to delete those users from a copied list that are not players, so that they are not iterated  in the constructor. I have a better idea: Simply skip over those users that you don't like, e.g.

```
for (User user : users) {
  if (!user.isPlayer()) continue;

  ... // score summation
}
```

Why are you using `BigDecimal`s? This is only reasonable when you have a scoring system that actually uses arbitrary fractional values (which is quite unusual). Most systems use integer scores or fixed point values, which can easily be translated to integers. Even if scores can be arbitrary values, an insignificant loss of precision *may* be acceptable. But this relies on the number of scores and the problem space, which I do not know about.